# A kaleidoscopic coloring of the plane

Tags: real-analysis, mg.metric-geometry, measure-theory, harmonic-analysis, geometric-measure-theory

> **Problem.** Is there a partition $\mathbb R^2=A\sqcup B$ of the Euclidean plane into two Lebesgue measurable sets such that for any disk $D$ of the unit radius we get  $\lambda(A\cap D)=\lambda(B\cap D)=\frac12\lambda(D)$?

(I.V.Protasov called such partitions *kaleidoscopic*).

Observe that for the $\ell_1$- or $\ell_\infty$-norms on the plane such partitions exist: just take a suitable chessboard coloring.

The problem can be reformulated in terms of convolutions: *Is there a measurable function $f:\mathbb R^2\to\{1,-1\}$ such that its convolution with the characteristic function $\chi_D$ of the unit disk $D$ is identically zero?*

(The problem was posed 08.11.2015 by T.Banakh and I.Protasov on [page 19](http://www.math.lviv.ua/szkocka/viewpage.php?vol=0&page=19) of [Volume 0](http://www.math.lviv.ua/szkocka/viewbook.php?vol=0) of the [Lviv Scottish Book](http://www.math.lviv.ua/szkocka)).

Comment: About the tag scottish-book, see the meta discussion: https://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/3948/tag-referring-to-a-book/3949

Comment: I'll record the basic observations in the Fourier domain: Let $f$ be the stated function, let $\hat{f}$ be its Fourier transform and let $\hat{\chi_D}$ be the Fourier transform of $\chi_D$. Then $\hat{f} \hat{\chi_D}$ is orthogonal to every character of $\mathbb{R}^2$. In my naive nonanalyst way, I think this means $\hat{f}$ is supported on the zeroes of $\hat{\chi_D}$. According to Mathematica, $\hat{\chi_D}(k_1, k_2) = 2 \pi \tfrac{J_1(k)}{k}$ where $J_1$ is the first Bessel function and $k = \sqrt{k_1^2+k_2^2}$. Unfortunately, $J_1$ has infinitely many zeroes.

Comment: I seem to see a 3-color kaleidoscope for the perfect hexagonal ball.

Comment: Do you know any plane figure (maybe nonconvex) without kaleidoscopic colorings? (wrt parallel translations)

Comment: @AntonPetrunin No, I do not know such a figure. It seems that for any triangle a kaleidoscopic coloring does exist.