# Move one element of finite set out from A in plane

Tags: set-theory, real-analysis, mg.metric-geometry, polymath16

Suppose we are given two sets, $S$ and $A$ in the plane, such that $S$ is finite, with a special point, $s_0$, while neither $A$ nor its complement is a null-set, i.e., the outer Lebesgue measure of $A$ and $A^c=\mathbb R^2\setminus A$ are both non-zero. Can we find two congruent copies of $S$, $f_1(S)$ and $f_2(S)$, such that $f_1^{-1}(f_1(S)\cap A)\Delta f_2^{-1}(f_2(S)\cap A)=\{s_0\}$, i.e., $s_0$ is the only element of $S$ that goes in to/out of $A$ when we go from $S_1$ to $S_2$?

My motivation is to extend a Falconer-Croft proof that works for measurable sets, see the details [here](https://dustingmixon.wordpress.com/2019/08/05/polymath16-fourteenth-thread-automated-graph-minimization/#comment-24068).
It [is easy to see](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/338576/can-planar-set-contain-even-many-vertices-of-every-unit-equilateral-triangle/338579#338579) that this can be done when the elements of $S$ are the three vertices of an equilateral triangle; in fact, the same trick works whenever $S\setminus\{s_0\}$ falls on a line, which doesn't contain $s_0$.

The problem seems quite similar to the finite Steinhaus problem/Jackson sets, as Laczkovich has pointed out.

Comment: You reverted my tag edit, but this question has little to do with real analysis.

Comment: @YCor Yes, because I think that many such problems are tagged real-anal, like https://mathoverflow.net/questions/219860, and I also had such problems on my real-anal class at the uni. While this is debatable, I'm sure that this question has nothing to do with discrete-geometry, which you've tagged it.

Comment: Agreed on discrete geometry. I don't think the linked post fits real-analysis either. On the other hand both clearly lack measure-theory.

Comment: @YCor Yes, that's my main problem too, that if I ask a measure-theory type question about non-measurable sets, then it's hard to tag it. Btw, I've also tagged my previous, similar question real-anal: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/337847

Comment: "Translate" in title, "congruent" in body. I think you mean "congruent".