# Odd Steinhaus problem for finite sets

Tags: set-theory, real-analysis, mg.metric-geometry

Call a finite subset $S$ of the plane with an even number of points an *odd Jackson set*, if there is an $A\subset \mathbb R^2$ such that $A$ meets every congruent copy of $S$ in an odd number of points.

> Are there any odd Jackson sets?

For a bit of history of related questions (and an explanation of the nomenclature), see [here](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0603235).
For my motivation, see [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/338437/move-one-element-of-finite-set-out-from-a-in-plane).

Comment: So, an odd Jackson set has an even number of points. Sounds odd to me.